# How to solve $\frac{n(n-1)}{2} \times 3^{n-2} = 5103$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have worked out that

$$\frac{n(n-1)}{2} \times 3^{n-2} = 5103$$

It follows that

$$n(n-1) \times 3^{n-2} = 10206$$

Expanding the left we get

$$(3^{n-2})(n^2) + (3^{n-2})(-n) = 10206$$

What is the next step in the solution?

Comment: My suggestion: show that this function is increasing and guess a solution. Its uniqueness will follow.

Comment: Really if you just checked the first few values of $n$ that's probably the fastest way to do it.

Comment: Thats how I did it originally but I wanted an elegant way.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're looking for an integer solution:

Factor $5103 = 3^6 \times 7$.  Evidently $7$ is not a factor of $3^{n-2}$, so it must be a factor of $n(n-1)$.  Since $7$ is prime, it must therefore be either $n$ or $n-1$, and either trial-and-error or observing that $6$ is divisible by $3$ and $8$ isn't yields $n = 7$.

Comment: I really love this solution, thanks. Its so beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{n(n-1)}{2} \times 3^{n-2} = 5103$$
$$n(n-1)3^n=91854$$
$$n(n-1)3^n=7(6)3^7$$
Now take the corresponding values to see how much value  of $n$ will be

Comment: Darn, you beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$5103=3^6 \times 7$$

This gives you a good upperbound on $n$.

**Hint 2:**
$$3 \cdot 7 =\frac{6 \cdot 7}{2} $$

If you are looking for integer solutions, the above two hints should solve it. If you need real solutions:

**Hint 3** For $n \geq 1$ the LHS is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

$$n(n-1) \cdot 3^{n-2} = 10206 = 42 \cdot 3^5$$
$$n(n-1)\cdot 3^{n} = 42 \cdot 3^7$$
$$n=7$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{n(n-1)}{2} \cdot3^{n-2}=5103=3^6\cdot7\Rightarrow\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\space \text {must be odd and }\space n-2\le 6$$
It follows at once $n=7$